# how to write condition in interpolation instead of *ngIf

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am using 2 language in my application for that I written it in 2 `<option>` tag. How can I write these both condition in one `<option>` tag using interpolation?

```
<option *ngIf="this.language=='en' || category.odiyaName==null" [value]="category.id">
  {{category.name}}
</option>
<option *ngIf="this.language=='or' && category.odiyaName" [value]="category.id">
  {{category.odiyaName}}
</option>
```

Comment: Technically you can't in this case because your conditions are not exhaustive. In general, you can use the ternary syntax `{{condition ? valueWhenTrue : valueWhenFalse}}`. But in this case it changes the  semantics

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the condition in interpolation. See the "parenthesis" enclosed the condition, and how it's unnecessary the use of this in this.language. I used also the "safe" operator to check if is null odiyaName and the operator "!" -else, if category.odyaName is "" will pass your condition

```
<option [value]="category.id">
    {{(language=='en' || !category?.odiyaName)
              ?category.name
              :category.odiyaName}}
</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if else block to show the option.

```
<option [value]="category.id">
  <ng-container *ngIf="this.language=='en' || category.odiyaName==null; else elseBlock">
    {{category.name}}
  </ng-container>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <ng-container *ngIf="this.language=='or' && category.odiyaName">
      {{category.odiyaName}}
    </ng-container>
  </ng-template>
</option>
```

Comment: You can also use the condition in interpolation

Comment: @aashu1807 please accept the answer if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Basically write your logic on component and pass it template to simplify the Html.

```
<option [value]="category.id"> {{checkLanguage(category)}} </option>
```

Component(.ts) file:

```
 checkLanguage(category){ 
  if(this.language==='en' || !category.odiyaName){
    return category.name
  }else if(this.language=='or' && category.odiyaName){
    return category.odiyaName;
 }
}
```